# Comparing two polynomials with vector's coefficients C++

Tags: c++, vector

This code is supposed to output the largest coefficient of 2 different polynomials, but if the first one is larger than the second, it doesn't compile correctly.

So, if the first polynomial is 1 - 2x +4x^3 and the second polynomial is -x + 5x^2 - 3x^6. It will work since the second polynomial is larger than the first.

It posts a "vector subscript out of range" error whenever the first polynomial is larger than the second

```
class Polynomial {
public:
Polynomial();
Polynomial(const vector<int>& coeffs);

int Degree() const;
int Coefficient(int k) const;
void print() const;
private:
vector<int>coefficient;

int main(){
//Variable and vector for inputs
vector<int> coefficient;
int input = 0;
//Welcome message
cout << "Welcome! Please input the coefficients of the first polynomial p(x).\nWhen you are finished, enter -12345.\n";

//While loop - if input isn't -12345, put the input into coefficient.
while (input != -12345){
    cin >> input;
    coefficient.push_back(input);
}

//Deletes -12345
coefficient.pop_back();

//Puts coefficient values into constructor
Polynomial first(coefficient);

//Prints first polynomial
cout << "\nYour first polynomial is p(x) = ";
first.print();

//Prints degrees of first polynomial
cout << ".\np(x) has degree " << first.Degree();
int degree1 = first.Degree();

//Prints transformation of first polynomial
cout << ".\nThe transform of p(x) is ";
first.Transform();

//clears the values in coefficient for second polynomial inputs.
coefficient.clear();

//Inputs the second polynomial's coefficients.
cout << ".\n\nPlease input the coefficients of the second polynomial q(x).\n";
//Had to use do-while because while loop wouldn't work.
do {
    cin >> input;
    coefficient.push_back(input);

} while (input != -12345);

//Deletes -12345
coefficient.pop_back();

//Puts coefficients into second polynomial
Polynomial second(coefficient);

//Prints second polynomial
cout << "\nYour second polynomial is q(x) = ";
second.print();

cout << ".\nq(x) has degree " << second.Degree();
int degree2 = second.Degree();

if (degree1 > degree2){
    cout << ".\n\nThe coefficient of x^" << degree1 << " in p(x) is " << first.Coefficient(degree1);
    cout << ".\nThe coefficient of x^" << degree1 << " in q(x) is " << second.Coefficient(degree1);
}
else{
    cout << ".\n\nThe coefficient of x^" << degree2 << " in p(x) is " << first.Coefficient(degree2);
    cout << ".\nThe coefficient of x^" << degree2 << " in q(x) is " << second.Coefficient(degree2);
}

int Polynomial::Degree() const{
int number = 0;
for (size_t i = 0, size = coefficient.size(); i < size; i++){
    if (coefficient[i] != 0)
        number = i;
}
return number;
}

int Polynomial::Coefficient(int k) const{
if (coefficient[k] != 0)
    return coefficient[k];
else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the concrete error you get. "Doesn't compile" is too vague. Moreover, it doesn't make any sense in this case because whether the program compiles cannot depend on runtime values. The code that you posted always returns `coefficient[k]` and does not choose a "larger coefficient" in any way (it doesn't even compare anything). The `if` statement is completely useless, unless the comparison operator `!=` for whatever type `coefficient[k]` is, is overloaded in a strange way.

Comment: Sorry about this, still a bit new to here and wording questions. More information: if the first polynomial is 1-2x+4x^3 and the second polynomial is -x+5x^2-3x^6. The highest degree is 6, so the first polynomial's coefficient would be 0 while the second polynomial's coefficient would be -3.
Whenever I run the code with the first polynomial being larger, I get a "vector subscript out of range" error message.

Comment: @stevenctran That's good to know, but without a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we cannot see how and even whether the code you posted is in any way related to this. And please update the question whenever you provide more details that describe the problem. Others don't want to read through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: I can say so much: the error message you get means that you are accessing some vector (probably the coefficients) at a `k` that is out of bounds. Maybe, you only construct the vector up to the highest power (3 for the first polynomial) but to compare it with the second, you check element `k=6` to compare with the coefficient to `x^6`? This element does not exist. Maybe, you have to replace the `if` by something that actually makes sense: my guess is that it should return 0 whenever the `k` is out of bounds (because then that power doesn't exist).

Comment: Your code does not compile (the `Polynomial` class declaration is not complete and some definitions are missing). But what is there confirms my guess: You are accessing the coefficient vector of the smaller-degree polynomial at the position of the highest power of the larger-degree polynomial, which is beyond the vector's end (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `coefficient` vector only runs up to the index of the highest power of the polynomial (i.e. it has 4 elements if `x^3` is the highest power), try replacing the function by

```
int Polynomial::Coefficient(int k) const{
    if (k < coefficient.size())
        return coefficient[k];
    else
        return 0;
}
```